# how could Karna be mistaken for a charioteer's son?

Tags: karna

His mother Kunti is described as beautiful, intelligent, and shrewd.
His father is the Sun-God.

Shouldn't he have displayed Tejas far exceeding a Charioteer's son?

Comment: I mean, they never called him charioteer. They called him Sutaputra right? Tejasvi Son adopted by a charioteer. I didn’t understand the question actually